# Upcoming changes to Alexa-related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

To formalize developer support for Alexa developers, the AWS Collective will be adding tags related to Alexa.

Ahead of that, Stack Overflow CMs will execute some changes to Alexa-related tags as detailed below.

AWS is crafting tag wiki entries for all of the tags that will be added to the collective.

| current tag | merge target | rationale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [alexa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa) (2449 questions) | [alexa-skills-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-skills-kit) (1906 questions) | The tag is too broad and is just a dumping ground; Most of the time it's used in conjunction with other tags. AWS will assess and retag older questions related to Alexa Internet ahead of the merge, using the new tag `alexa-internet` (which would not be part of the AWS Collective). |
| [alexa-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-app) (206 questions) | [alexa-skills-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-skills-kit) (1908 questions) | The tag is almost exclusively used to refer to Alexa skills, not apps. App and Skill are used synonymously as external communities often refer to skills as apps (as noted on the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/alexa-app/info)). To avoid confusion with the actual Alexa mobile app or Alexa for Apps program, we propose to merge these tags. |
| [alexa-skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-skill) (1156 questions) | [alexa-skills-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-skills-kit) (1906 questions) | [alexa-skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-skill) is already a synonym of [alexa-skills-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-skills-kit) (since 2016) but the tags were never merged. So in this case, the proposal is to simply complete the merge. |
| [alexa-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-intent) (10 questions) | [alexa-interaction-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-interaction-model) (2 questions) | Intents are just one aspect of an interaction model, it would be more appropriate for these questions to be tagged as [alexa-interaction-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-interaction-model) |

| current tag name | proposed new name | rationale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ask-smapi-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ask-smapi-sdk) (6 questions) | alexa-smapi | This would ensure the tag begins with "alexa-" and also, the "smapi-sdk" tag is too specific, it's a subset of the Skill Management API more broadly. Thus "alexa-smapi" would be appropriate both for SMAPI API questions and SMAPI SDK questions. |
| [alexa-flash-briefing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-flash-briefing) (7 questions) | alexa-flash-briefing-skill | This way, both smart home skills and flash briefing skills (both sub-types of skills) follow similar naming conventions of ending with '-skill" |

For context, the other tags being added to the collective are [alexa-account-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-account-linking) (13 questions), [alexa-presentation-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-presentation-language) (29 questions), [alexa-sdk-nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-sdk-nodejs) (30 questions), the creation-in-progress tags [alexa-sdk-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-sdk-python) and [alexa-smart-home-skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-smart-home-skill).

This post will be open for feedback until October 3 and the changes will be made soon afterward.

Comment: Will the tag [alexa] be blacklisted? I feel like it would be recreated pretty quickly.

Comment: @dan1st: In general, we'd only block a tag if it's been removed and then recreated – we don't generally do so proactively.

Comment: The tag changes have been completed.